# Which operators commute with integration?

Tags: operator-theory

Leibniz proved that $D_y\cdot D^{-1}_x=D_{x}^{-1}\cdot D_y$, where $D_x=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. It follows that $D^n_y\cdot D^{-1}_x=D_{x}^{-1}\cdot D^n_y$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

I've not been formally introduced to fractional calculus, so I'm curious as to what is the maximum set of $\alpha$ such that
$$D^{\alpha}_y\cdot D^{-1}_x=D_{x}^{-1}\cdot D^{\alpha}_y$$
is true?

For what type of $\alpha,\beta$ is
$$D^{\alpha}_y\cdot D^{\beta}_x=D_{x}^{\beta}\cdot D^{\alpha}_y$$
true?

I assume that $D^{\alpha}_y\cdot D^{\beta}_x=D_{x}^{\beta}\cdot D^{\alpha}_y$ immediately implies that the operators operate on functions which are $\alpha$ 'differentiable' in $x$ and $\beta$ 'differentiable' in $y$ (' ' used as if $\alpha=-1$ the functions have to be '$-1$ differentiable' $=$ *integrable* in $x$).

Comment: I may have mistagged this as operator theory, feel free to edit if so.